# Tkinter IntVar returning PY_VAR0 instead of value

Tags: python, python-3.x, checkbox, tkinter

I have a Checkbutton and an `IntVar` object associated with it, but when I try to get the value of the `var`, I am receiving `PY_VAR0`.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def show_state():
    print(var)

var = IntVar()

cbtn = Checkbutton(root, text='Check', variable=var, command=show_state)
cbtn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Why am I getting `PY_VAR0`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`var` is a reference to a `Tkinter.IntVar` object. You need to call its [`get`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) method to access the value that it represents:

```
print(var.get())
```

Comment: I lost way to much time over this, kinda unintuitiv.