# Variable value changes from string to instance

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, types, tkinter

I am trying to put together my first little program, but I keep having some difficulties. I am using data from an SQLite DB, but I changed the code below a bit so it's usable without the DB itself. The `list_base` and `List_sold_at_base` functions usually would pull data from a DB (base and commodities info from the Freelancer game, so I can list what commodities are sold on what base).

What the program should do is build up a list of all bases when the 'bases' button is pressed and put this in the `Combobox`.

When selecting an option from the `Combobox` this selection should be stored in the variable `v`, and update when another base is selected. This works. the variable `v` is a `str` type so far.

The `Goods sold at base` button calls a function that takes `v` and uses it to check in de DB what goods are sold at this base, and prints this out in a list.

However, now the variable `v` isn't a string type anymore (which it should be for the function to work properly), but an `instance`. Somehow this gets changed but I can't figure out where and why. I put in a couple of print statements to see how and where, but they don't really show it all that well.

```
from Tkinter import *
import csv, sqlite3, sys
from ttk import Combobox

root = Tk()

v = StringVar()


def on_field_change(index, value, op):
    print "combobox updated to ", boxBases.get()
    v = boxBases.get()
    print 'v is', v
    print type(v)

def List_bases():
    dropdownBases = []
    for i in ['base1', 'base2', 'base3', 'base4',]:
        dropdownBases.append(i)
    return dropdownBases

def List_sold_at_base(selbase):
    goodsSoldAtBase = []
    sb=selbase
    print "selbase value (v) is", selbase
    print "selbase type is ", type(selbase)
    dataFromDB = [['base1', 'Cobalt 275', 'Copper 180'],['base2', 'High Temp Alloy 280', 'Mining Machinery 130'], ['base3', 'H-Fuel 240', 'Oxygen 6', 'Water 18'], ['base4', 'Hydrocarbons 40', 'Polymers 107']]
    for i in dataFromDB:
        if i[0] == sb:
            goodsSoldAtBase.append(i)
    print "goods sold at base list: ", goodsSoldAtBase
    print " "
    print v
    print type(v)

def base():
    dropdownBases = List_bases()
    boxBases.config(values=dropdownBases)
    print "bases!"

def goods():
    List_sold_at_base(v)
    print '=========='

dropdownBases = []

v.trace('w',on_field_change)
boxBases = Combobox(root, textvar=v, values=dropdownBases)
boxBases.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

baseButton=Button(root, text="bases", command=base)
baseButton.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

goodsButton = Button(root, text="Goods sold at base", command=goods)
goodsButton.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter IntVar returning PY\_VAR0 instead of value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768455/tkinter-intvar-returning-py-var0-instead-of-value)

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at it later!

Comment: I don't understand why you want to change it to string? You can always get the value of it using `v.get()` and change its value using `v.set("new_value")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input. I got it to work by trying around with the .get() a bit more and taking out 1 function that basically just called another function. I cut out the middle man (goods() ).

```
from Tkinter import *
import csv, sqlite3, sys
from ttk import Combobox

root = Tk()

v = StringVar()


def on_field_change(index, value, op):
    v = boxBases.get()
    print 'v is', v


def List_bases():
    dropdownBases = []
    for i in ['base1', 'base2', 'base3', 'base4',]:
        dropdownBases.append(i)
    return dropdownBases

def List_sold_at_base():
    goodsSoldAtBase = []
    sb=v.get()
    dataFromDB = [['base1', 'Cobalt 275', 'Copper 180'],['base2', 'High Temp Alloy 280', 'Mining Machinery 130'], ['base3', 'H-Fuel 240', 'Oxygen 6', 'Water 18'], ['base4', 'Hydrocarbons 40', 'Polymers 107']]
    for i in dataFromDB:
        if i[0] == sb:
            goodsSoldAtBase.append(i)
    print "goods sold at base list: ", goodsSoldAtBase

def base():
    dropdownBases = List_bases()
    boxBases.config(values=dropdownBases)
    print "bases!"

dropdownBases = []

v.trace('w',on_field_change)
boxBases = Combobox(root, textvar=v, values=dropdownBases)
boxBases.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

baseButton=Button(root, text="bases", command=base)
baseButton.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

goodsButton = Button(root, text="Goods sold at base", command=List_sold_at_base)
goodsButton.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```