# TKinter Label Not Updating

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I know this question has been asked several times already, but none of the solutions I see on the other posts are working for me (I'm sure I'm probably implementing them wrong) so here goes.

I'm working on a simple search interface to search for an ID in a list of IDs and return the properties associated with that id, which I would like to be displayed. I am currently attempting to use tkinter on Python 3.6 for this, but I am open to using a different method if that would be better.

My current code follows:

```
from tkinter import *

class User(object):

    def __init__(self, uid, name, cc):
        self.uid = uid
        self.name = name
        self.cc = cc

ID1 = User('111111','NAME', 0000)

ID2 = User('222222','NAME', 0000)

ID3 = User('333333','NAME', 0000)

users = [ID1, ID2, ID3]

lst = ""

search_input = ""

main = Tk()
main.title("Field Lookup")
main.geometry('320x240')

frame1 = Frame(main, height=200, width=200)
frame1.pack()

l1 = Label(frame1, text="Enter User ID")
l1.pack()

entry = Entry(frame1, width=30, textvariable=search_input)
entry.pack()

l2 = Label(frame1, textvariable=lst)
l2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

def updt():
    l2.configure(text=lst)
    main.update_idletasks()

def search():
    for u in users:
        if u==search_input:
            lst = u.uid,u.name,u.cc
            print(lst)
            updt()

def clear():
    entry.delete(0, END)
    lst = None
    updt()

button1 = Button(frame1, text="Search", command=search)
button1.pack(side=LEFT)

button2 = Button(frame1, text="Clear", command=clear)
button2.pack(side=RIGHT)

main.mainloop()
```

This works for the most part, but the label which should return the results will not update. In addition to the updt() function I currently have in, I have also tried calling main.update() within the body of the search function, as well as main.update_idletasks(). I also tried calling both of those just before main.mainloop(), again to no effect. Currently everything is working on this, including the clear function, and the search function has been tested independently to ensure it is working properly, so the issue is with the label not updating as far as I can tell. I'm very new to Python, so any help would be massively appreciated.

** EDIT **

I found that when I print my variables search_input and lst to the console, they are reading as PY_VAR0 and PY_VAR1, rather than printing the strings they should contain. I think that I need to find a way to access these contained strings, but I am not sure how to go about doing so. Simply casting as str() results in only a string of PY_VAR(n)

**EDIT 2**

Searching for the PY_VAR issue yielded [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768455/tkinter-intvar-returning-py-var0-instead-of-value), which fixed my issue. Working code follows:

```
from tkinter import *

class User(object):

    def __init__(self, uid, name, cc):
        self.uid = uid
        self.name = name
        self.cc = cc
##Had to set cc variable as string to work with join method
ID1 = User('111111','NAME', '0000')

ID2 = User('222222','NAME', '0000')

ID3 = User('333333','NAME', '0000')

users = [ID1, ID2, ID3]

main = Tk()
main.title("Field Lookup")
main.geometry('320x240')

frame1 = Frame(main, height=300, width=200)
frame1.pack()

l1 = Label(frame1, text="Enter User ID")
l1.pack()

lst = StringVar()

search_input = StringVar()

entry = Entry(frame1, width=30, textvariable=search_input)
entry.pack()

l2 = Label(frame1, textvariable=lst)
l2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

def updt():
    main.update_idletasks()

def search():
    for u in users:
        if u.uid==search_input.get():
            lst.set(', '.join((u.uid,u.name,u.cc)))
            updt()

def clear():
    entry.delete(0, END)
    lst.set('')
    updt()

button1 = Button(frame1, text="Search", command=search)
button1.pack(side=LEFT)

button2 = Button(frame1, text="Clear", command=clear)
button2.pack(side=RIGHT)

main.mainloop()
```

Now to just pretty it up some. All help received was much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some minor changes:

You need to pass a `StringVar` as the value for `textvariable`.

```
lst = StringVar()
```

Remove `l2.configure(textvariable=lst)`. Updates to `lst` updates the text for the label.

In `clear()`, set `lst` to an empty string.

```
lst.set('')
```

In `search()`, set `lst` to the result.

```
lst.set(','.join((u.uid,u.name,u.cc)))
```

Comment: When I try to set lst = StringVar(), it gives me the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Path\Python\Scripts and Programs\search_box.py", line 24, in <module>
    lst = StringVar()
  File "C:\Path\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 477, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "C:\Path\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 314, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'

Comment: RE: My last comment, the issue was with the placement of the stringvar() call, it was invoked before I invoked tk(). But I am still having the same issue; my label will not display.

Comment: `l2.configure(text=lst)` should be `l2.configure(textvariable=lst)`

Answer (score 1):

In your `search` function, you iterate over `users`, which are class objects (`ID1`, etc.), and compare them to your entry string, which always evaluates to `False`.

`if u==search_input:` should really be `if u.uid == search_input:` (or `u.name` if you're searching thru names).

Comment: You were on the right track but looking at the wrong side. u was evaluating to the correct string, but search_input was coming out as an object, which was remedied by calling search_input.get()