# Set working directory through tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code which basically helps me get first the path of a folder and then set the working directory to that specific folder.

I do get the following error message though:

```
os.chdir(sourcePath)  # Provide the path here
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PY_VAR0'
```

The code:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import glob, os, shutil

def browse_button():
    # Allow user to select a directory and store it in global var
    # called folder_path
    global folder_path
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folder_path.set(filename)
    print(filename)

def set_dir():
    sourcePath = str(folder_path)
    os.chdir(sourcePath)  # Provide the path here


root = Tk()

folder_path = StringVar()

lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=folder_path)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)

buttonBrowse = Button(text="Browse folder", command=browse_button)
buttonBrowse.grid(row=2, column=1)
buttonSetDir = Button(root, text='Set directory', command=set_dir).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter IntVar returning PY\_VAR0 instead of value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768455/tkinter-intvar-returning-py-var0-instead-of-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
sourcePath = str(folder_path)
```

with:

```
sourcePath = folder_path.get()
```

`str(folder_path)` basically gets the variable's [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) interpreter name.