# Displays PY_VAR4 instead of number

Tags: python, tkinter

```
x = IntVar()
x.set(1)
def add():
    x.set(x.get()+1)
```

I am using this piece of code to update the question number on a tkinter quiz I am making.

```
self.recordNum = Label(self.quizf, text=x)
self.recordNum.pack()

self.Submit = Button(self.quizf, text = 'submit', command=lambda:[self.confirmAnswer(),add()])
```

I used `lambda` so I could have two commands in the same button which I need as `self.confirmAnswer` runs the if statement to check the answer and the `add` command activates the first piece of code displayed above.

When I run the quiz `PY_VAR4` displays instead of a number, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: This is not a proper use of `lambda`. If you need to do more than one thing, create a proper function for the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.recordNum = Label(self.quizf, text=x.get())
self.recordNum.pack()

self.Submit = Button(self.quizf, text = 'submit', command=lambda:[self.confirmAnswer(),add()])
```

In the label, you have to use `x.get()` instead of just `x`, as you want the value of `x`.

Just using `x` will reference to the object which is simply `PY_VAR`. The `4` at the end of the reference simply denotes the variable number to distinguish between other variables. In this case, the program in total so far has 5 variables declared, as references start from `PY_VAR0` ... all the way to... `PY_VAR4`.

Using `x.get()` will instead get the value stored in the object from which the reference points to.

So instead of: `self.recordNum = Label(self.quizf, text=x)`

use: `self.recordNum = Label(self.quizf, text=x.get())`

Possible duplicate of: [Tkinter IntVar returning PY_VAR0 instead of value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768455/tkinter-intvar-returning-py-var0-instead-of-value)

Comment: thanks, works now!

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: If only I had found that other article that makes mine a duplicate before asking the question, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use “textvariable” as argument for your variable. Then the label will update itself.