# Double entry widgets in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to complete an ATM program using GUI in Python.

**Problem:**

At the start, my program generates a window of Tkinter that takes PIN as input from entry widgets using 0-9 buttons.Entry button takes
`Entry (root, textvariable=text_Input)` while `text_input=StringVar()`
 program compares the entered PIN with the data available in the files.

If PIN matches, my program goes to another function through <kbd>Enter</kbd> button, destroys the previous root and opens a new one. Here I need to enter some amount to withdraw or deposit. I am using `Entry` widget here again by doing

```
inp= StringVar()
Entry (root1, textvarible=inp)
```

I used withdraw button which sends this (`inp`) to `withdraw` function. When I print that (`inp`), it gives `PY_Var16`, `PY_Var22`.

Comment: To get the value from a tkinter Variable like StringVar, you need to use the `get()` method. Try `print(inp.get())`.

Comment: BTW, you should never have more than one root window (`Tk()` call) in your program. You need to clear out the old root and reuse it. Using a `Frame` would make that very easy.

Comment: Don't destroy the Tkinter root window and then create a new one. When you do `tk.Tk()` that doesn't just create a window, it also creates an instance of the Tcl interpreter that is the basis of Tkinter. If you need multiple windows take a look at the Toplevel widget. Also, the root window is the root of all the Tkinter objects you create. When you destroy it any widgets, StringVars, etc you created become invalid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter IntVar returning PY\_VAR0 instead of value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768455/tkinter-intvar-returning-py-var0-instead-of-value)

Comment: This is the only thing i didn't try because im very new to iy. Thanx a lot i hope it works once i get back to it

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `print(inp)` with `print(inp.get())`