# Tkinter - variable to trace change in other variable

Tags: python, callback, tkinter, observers

So I have this code snippet:

```
for p in self.ProductNames:
    OptionMenuVar = StringVar()
    menu = OptionMenu(self.FrameProducts, OptionMenuVar, *self.ProductNames)
    OptionMenuVar.set(p)

    AgeVar = StringVar()
    AgeEntry = Entry(self.FrameProducts,width=15,textvariable=AgeVar,state="readonly",justify=CENTER)
```

which generates this UI:

[image]

### Question

How do I trace changes in `OptionMenuVar` and update `AgeVar` based on the selected value?

I've read [The Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). I guess I know how to trace changes in `OptionMenuVar` but I still don't know how to:

1. detect the new value
2. update `AgeVar` according to the new value

Comment: You can a `StringVar` object's `trace()` method to call some function whenever it's value is changed. In your case `OptionMenuVar.trace("w", mycallback)`. See [_The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)_](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). The `"w"` is the `mode` and means call when "written".

Comment: Yes. Already aware of that approach. Just don't know how to apply it :)

Comment: Just figured it out...

Comment: Write a function that when called gets the current value of `OptionMenuVar` and sets the value of `AgeVar`.

Comment: It's difficult to read your code because you're not following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) with regards to your variable names, which all look like class names because of their use of CapWords, (aka CamelCase).

Comment: Hope you'll cut me some slack this time. the main thing is the we were able to trace changes is one variable and apply them to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is the way to do it:

```
def OnOptionMenuChnage(omv,av, *pargs):
    print omv.get(), av.get()
    # do more. set av value based on omv value

OptionMenuVar.trace("w", lambda *pargs: OnOptionMenuChnage(OptionMenuVar,AgeVar, *pargs))
```

### Complete code

```
for p in self.ProductNames:
    OptionMenuVar = StringVar()
    menu = OptionMenu(self.FrameProducts, OptionMenuVar, *self.ProductNames)
    OptionMenuVar.set(p)

    AgeVar = StringVar()
    AgeEntry = Entry(self.FrameProducts,width=15,textvariable=AgeVar,state="readonly",justify=CENTER)

    def OnOptionMenuChnage(omv,av, *pargs):
        print omv.get(), av.get()
        # do more. set av value based on omv value

    OptionMenuVar.trace("w", lambda *pargs: OnOptionMenuChnage(OptionMenuVar,AgeVar, *pargs))
```

All the credit to Marcin  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23986161/1798187).